# How can register globally all controllers for a area in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc area named "Admin", and inside have 3 controllers, but can be 5 or more, and for any controller i have to put [Area("Admin")] attribute above the controller class definition.

I don't want to do this: [Area("Admin")] for all controllers inside this admin area,

Can i register all controllers for that area in mvc 6?

Answer (score 0):

**For MVC6**, You need to decorate the controllers with `Area` attribute. if you do not prefer to add this to individual controllers, you may simply create a base call which has Area decoration and inherit your other controllers from that.

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class AdminArea : Controller
{
}

public class OrdersController : AdminArea
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class ProductsController : AdminArea
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**MVC 5 and below**

You do not need to put that attribute on your controller name, You can simply specify the area name in the area route registration.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", controller= "YourDefaultCtrl", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: I need a similar functionality but in MVC 6, that not resolve my problem

Comment: @JohanPino create a base class and inherit from that. See the updated answer.